# Getting the variables from a JOptionPane

Tags: java, swing

I have created a JOptionPane that pulls up a custom JPanel that takes in 2 JTextField's & A JComboBox. Upon hitting Save I would like to have the 3 values stored into global variables but have little experience with JOptionPane and making this work I have the following method that instantiates it:

```
    public void add() {
    JOptionPane.showOptionDialog(null,
        getPanel(),
        "Add A Shipment ",
        JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION, 
        JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE, null, 
        new String[]{"Add Shipment", "Cancel"},"default");
}
```

and the method that creates the custom popup

```
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
private JPanel getPanel() {
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout (8,8));

    //NORTH PANEL
    JPanel name = new JPanel();
    name.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,8));
    name.add(new JLabel("Title: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
    JTextField titleIn = new JTextField();
    titleIn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
    name.add(titleIn, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //CENTER PANEL
    JPanel trackID = new JPanel();
    trackID.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,8));
    trackID.add(new JLabel("Tracking #: "), BorderLayout.WEST);
    JTextField trackIn = new JTextField();
    trackIn.setPreferredSize(new Dimension(150, 20));
    trackID.add(trackIn, BorderLayout.EAST);

    //BOTTOM PANEL
    JPanel ship = new JPanel();
    ship.setLayout(new BorderLayout(8,8));

    String[] services = { "USPS", "UPS", "FedEx", "DHL" };
    @SuppressWarnings("rawtypes")
    JComboBox service = new JComboBox(services);
    service.setSelectedIndex(0);
    ship.add(service);

    panel.add(name, BorderLayout.NORTH);
    panel.add(trackID, BorderLayout.CENTER);
    panel.add(ship, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
    return panel;
}
```

Any easy way of assigning these as variables with the given code?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a class that extends JPanel, store the controls (the two JTextFields and the JComboBox) as fields of this class, pass an instance of this class to `JOptionPane.showOptionDialog()` and retrieve the values from the fields after the call.

Comment: Thank you for your response, that does in fact make sense. I created a subclass titled panelVar() that extends JPanel, input 3 fields and a constructor to take in all 3 fields and assign values, with methods to return the variables. My last question is where in the add() method to I pass the instance of panelVar() at?

Comment: You need to pass your instance as the second parameter to showOptionDialog().